# How to display response on HTML page after an XMLHTTPRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, ejs, onload

I am making my own project. I am sending out an AJAX request which will come back with a response. I want to parse out the response and display the data in a table. Like so:

```
<head>
<script>
var message = null;
function ajaxCallToServer() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); var url = "something"
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.onload = (res) => {
        console.log(res['target']['response']);
        message = res['target']['response']; // message is a JSON object
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
...
<body>
    <% if ( message) { %>
    <!--loop through message object to display message on the page-->
    <div class="table">
        <% for(key in message) { %>
        <% if(message.hasOwnProperty(key)) { %>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td key"><b><%= key %></b></div>
            <div class="td value"><%= message[key] %></div>
        </div>
        <% } %>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    <% } %>
</body>
```

I am assigning the variable message (which the console.log shows has the correct data) then printing it using ejs later in the page. The ejs does not print the ‘message’ and I suspect it has something to do with needing the page to re-load.. help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, 'message' is null when you call it.

Here you have a simple example on how to change de html of a DOM element dinamically.

**HTML**:

```
<p id="test">

</p>
```

**JS (ES6)**:

```
const test = document.getElementById('test');

test.innerHTML = "Tested";
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/

Quick-fix using your code:

```
<head>
<script>
var message = null;
function ajaxCallToServer() {
    var responseText = document.getElementById('response');
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); var url = "something"
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.onload = (res) => {
        console.log(res['target']['response']);
        message = res['target']['response'];
        responseText.innerHTML = message;

    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
...
<body>
    <p id="response"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: message is coming back as a JSON object

Comment: EJS is not the way to do this, you will have to do things with pure HTML and JS. You have option to use React or Vue in this project?

Comment: i think React is the way to go, gonna convert to React

Comment: Good choice! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your page cannot reload and still have the variable `message` set unless you post it to your site.

EJS only renders on load, so maybe you should have a look at [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org) or simply put the message into your body using `document.querySelector("body").innerHtml = message;`.

Here is a working example:

```js
var message;
function ajaxCallToServer() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    var url = "something"
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.onload = (res) => {
        console.log(res['target']['response']);
        message = res['target']['response'];
        document.querySelector("body").innerHtml = message;
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```